# Port Forward inside Router (DD-WRT)

Tags: proxy, port-forwarding, iptables, dd-wrt

I have configured an SSH tunnel on my DD-WRT router using the default port 22.

I would like to open another port on my router as a proxy port for SSH, say port 80, in case a firewall prevents me from connecting to port 22.  How do I do this?  I assume it may be a combination of  configuring `SSH TCP Forwarding` *(which I have left set "OFF" because I still can't find that it does anything when on)*, `Port Forward` *(which I have set to forward TCP 80 to 192.168.1.1:22)*, and `iptables` *(which I have not modified because I only topically understand them)*.

At present, I can access the SSH tunnel using port 22.  If I scan port 80, it shows open, but I cannot establish an SSH connection over it. I'm guessing my firewall is the issue.

Can someone answer how I should configure the router, using the GUI as much as possible, to proxy port 80 to 22 on localhost?

---

My configuration: DD-WRTv24-sp2, Build 14896

Current iptables configuration:

```
# OpenVPN
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 --source 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT

# Force-Filter DNS
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to $(nvram get lan_ipaddr)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to $(nvram get lan_ipaddr)
```

Comment: Could an administrator explain why my post was migrated from server fault?  Serverfault has far more a following for my tags than superuser.

Comment: Yes, I can. `dd-wrt` is an end-user/consumer networking system, making this a consumer/end-user question which is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on [SF].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Administration > Commands**, add the following line to the firewall configuration:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d $(nvram get wan_ipaddr) --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $(nvram get lan_ipaddr):22
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to open port 80 on the 'Internet' side to be forwarded to port 22 of a server on the 'LAN' side?

I'm not sure how to do that on DD-WRT, but I think you should do it in two steps:

1. Configure the DD-WRT to do "Port Forward" on ports 80 and 22 to the target server
2. Configure SSH on the target server to listen on ports 22 *and* 80.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -i /tmp/root/.ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -f -y -K 30 -R 0:localhost:80 tunnel.us.ngrok.com tcp 22
```